# Jersey JSON API fail with @ attributes

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

So I am using Jersey/javax.ws.rs for REST web API in Tomcat in Java.

I want to support both XML and JSON, so have cloned my XML API server class with a JSON one, and find/replace APPLICATION_XML with APPLICATION_JSON.

It mostly works, except both use the same transfer objects mapped like,

```
@XmlRootElement(name="chat")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChatMessage extends Config {
    public String message;
    @XmlAttribute
    public String app;
}
```

Calling the web APIs work, and return JSON like,

```
{"@app":"123", "message":"helloworld"}
```

But calling POST on the API with the same JSON fails, "request is syntactically incorrect", i.e. does not like the "@" for some reason.

If I remove the "@" it calls the API, but does not pass "id".

javax.ws.rs code is,

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/chat")
public ChatMessage chat(ChatMessage message, @Context HttpServletRequest requestContext) {
    ...
}
```

The XML version of the API works fine.

My currently solution for this bug is to duplicate the model classes as well, and copy from one to the other, but this kind of sucks.

Using Jersey 1.17, also same error in 1.19

Comment: Can you provide the JSON POST body?

Comment: And also can you put up the `Config` class, or whatever class has the `@id` attribute?

Comment: sry, changed id to app, code is above, but any class with an attribute has same issue